# How to use libarchive in iOS in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, libarchive

I want to add [libarchive](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive) to my app to be able to extract tar.gz.

As install instruction says, I took following steps:

- cmake -G "Xcode" ~/libarchive-download-dir/
- make
- make install

Now I have a `libarchive.14.dzlib` file. I added it to the project, and wants to call i.e. the following, like proposed in [examples](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/Examples)

```
r = archive_read_open_filename(a, "archive.tar", 10240);
```

but, method is not declared.

[image]

I guess I have to add a header to the project?! It is a dylib, I am not sure. But I do not found any appropriate header file in the build folder.

How can I use libarchive, what am I missing to call one method, which methods are available where is a header?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to add the header. The `archive.h` header that is in the `libarchive` directory is sufficient, you don't need the other ones.

Comment: are you sure archive.h is enough? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367979/libarchive-raise-compiler-error

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've simply forgotten to include the header file and so the compiler assumes any undefined functions return `int`.

Answer (score 0):

If you correctly downloaded libarchive sources, they should include source .cpp and .h files - look here https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/tree/master/libarchive