# libarchive raise compiler error in iOS in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, libarchive

I compiled `libarchive` with following commands

- cmake -G "Xcode" ~/libarchive-download-dir/
- make
- make install

and added `libarchive.14.dylib` and `achieve.h` to my project. But I got an compiler error. Any idea why?

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_archive_read_support_filter_all", referenced from:
>         -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang:
>   error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

I tried this code like [example](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/Examples) propose:

```
struct archive *a;
struct archive_entry *entry;
int r;

a = archive_read_new();
archive_read_support_filter_all(a);
archive_read_support_format_all(a);
r = archive_read_open_filename(a, "archive.tar.gz", 10240); // Note 1
```

I am worried about the warning too next to the code lines.

[image]

below the `lipo` return value

> lipo -info /Users/extjanos/Desktop/temp2/libarchive/libarchive.a 
>   input file /Users/extjanos/Desktop/temp2/libarchive/libarchive.a is
>   not a fat file Non-fat file:
>   /Users/extjanos/Desktop/temp2/libarchive/libarchive.a is architecture:
>   x86_64

Comment: Isn't this the same as your previous question (failing to include header file)?

Comment: nop, here as you see on the side `archive.h` is already added

Comment: Well those implicit declaration warnings show you have not included the correct header file.

Comment: It's a duplicate of the same question asked by you: [How to use libarchive in iOS in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33366924/how-to-use-libarchive-in-ios-in-xcode)

Comment: @János did you ever manage to solve this. I have downloaded library, it builds for mac, but for iOS i am having trouble building it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the header at the top of your file :

```
#import "archive.h"
```

As for the library did you add it to the list of linked libraries ? In your target settings got to "Build Phases" and check that it has been added to the "Link Binary With Libraries" list.

Also you must use the static library and not the shared one. Use `libarchive.a` instead of `libarchive.dylib`

Comment: thanks good idea, import line added, and I can see libarchive.dylib in "Link Binary With Libraries"

Comment: tried "libarchive.a" but got the same error now for ".a"

Comment: What is the result of this command : `lipo -info libarchive.a` ?

Comment: lipo says it has architecture: x86_64, see above

Comment: @János You haven't built the library correctly.  You need both simulator architectures (i386 and x86_64) as well as armv7, armv7s and arm64 device architectures all in one fat static library.

Comment: @trojanfoe I would expect either on simulator or on device I can run app, but not, both environment raises error

Comment: @János Well you can see that it is attempting to run on a 32-bit simulator (arch=i386) when you only have support for 64-bit simulator (arch=x86_64).

Comment: @János Try running it on an iPhone 5S or later simulator. All simulators up to iPhone 5 are 32bits if I remember correctly.

Comment: @trojanfoe do you have any idea how should I adjust build command up in the question to get fat static library?

Comment: @János That depends how you built the library.  It's non-trivial cross-compiling for iOS and combining the libraries into a single fat library.